# Python iterate the list with decimal precision

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pycharm

I used netCDF Python library to read netCDF variable which has list(variable) returns correct decimal precision as in the image (using PyCharm IDE). However, when I try to get the element by index, e.g: variable[0], it returns the rounded value instead (e.g: 5449865.55794), while I need 5449865.55793999997.

[image]

How can I iterate this list with correct decimal precision ?

Some basic code

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
nc_dataset = Dataset(self.get_file().get_filepath(), "r")
variable_name = "E" 
// netCDF file contains few variables (axis dimensions)
variable = nc_dataset.variables[variable_name]
variable is not a list but a netCDF object, however when using list() or variable[index] will return element value of the axis dimension.
```

Comment: we need a [mcve] please

Comment: I updated the code Jean, I'm not sure with this netCDF library though.

Comment: can you give more detail, Chris ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimals you are chasing are bogus. The difference is only in the way these numbers are represented on your screen, not in how they are stored in your computer.

Try the following to convince yourself

```
a = 5449865.55793999997
a
# prints 5449865.55794
```

The difference between the two numbers if we were to take them literally is 3x10^-11. The smallest difference a 64 bit floating point variable at the size of `a` can resolve is more than an order of magnitude larger. So your computer cannot tell these two decimal numbers apart.

But look at the bright side. Your data aren't corrupted by some mysterious process.

Comment: actually to get the correct precision, one can do like this

tmp = '{}'.format(variable[:].astype(numpy.dtype(decimal.Decimal)))

it will return string of array and parse it to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what suits your needs:

```
import decimal

print decimal.Decimal('5449865.55793999997')
```

Comment: thank but the problem is when I get element value: variable[0] it already returned 5449865.55794, then cannot use decimal() as in your example.

Comment: Then assign it as a list of `decimal` objects.  i.e. `data_list=[decmal.Decimal(num) for num in variable]` instead of `data_list=list(variable)`